# Emberjs and Ember data .13 saving related hasMany models unnecessarily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have some models with relationships resembling the following:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
       favorite_articles: DS.hasMany('App.FavoriteArticle')
       hella_favorite_articles: DS.hasMany('App.HellaFavoriteArticle')

App.FavoriteArticle = DS.Model.extend
       user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
       article: DS.belongsTo('App.Article')
       starred: DS.attr('boolean')

App.HellaFavoriteArticle = DS.Model.extend
       user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
       article: DS.belongsTo('App.Article')
       starred: DS.attr('boolean')

App.Article = DS.Model.extend
       favorite_article: belongsTo('App.Article')
       hella_favorite_article: belongsTo('App.Article')
```

Here is what is happening. Let's say I sideload all the models for a particular view. And in that view, there is an action to star the HellaFavoriteArticle (I know this is ridiculous).

When I hook all this up and click the action, Ember fires off a PUT to both the '/hella_favorite' and '/favorite' endpoints.

Why would this be? I would prefer it didn't, and I think it may be causing an error in fact, though I cannot yet confirm this. However, I do find that when I remove the relationship to the Article from the HellaFavoriteArticle model, Ember no longer fires off requests to both endpoints. So this caused me to surmise that Ember 'decides' to update both models based on the shared relationship.

On the one hand that is some pretty crafty magic, but on the other, I don't know where to go to override this.

TIA!

Comment: I guess what is really weird is that Ember / Ember-Data hits both endpoints, but only on the first update, on subsequent updates, it only hits the endpoint I need it to hit… so why does it only do it once? Maybe because it fails to update the model internally?

Comment: Can you post the code for you templates and your controllers? A jsbin or jsfiddle illustrating the problem would be ideal.

Comment: I spent some significant time, trying to mock out an example without fixtures, but using a static service to serve JSON wouldn't recreate the bug. I may spin up a simple Heroku app to see if I can reproduce.